# Views and some Relationships can't import to Visual Studio when Using Entity Framework in C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I make some Views & Stored Procedure from my database in SQL Server 2008,

but when I using Entity Framework to import my db to Visual Studio, some Views and Relationships can't import in C# WPF

My View in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
dbo.View1
```

My Code in Visual Studio, after make a new Entity Connection:

```
Entities1 db = new Entities1();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.View1.ToList(); // Error Shown
```

Comment: What error is shown? Have you ensured the View is selected in the list of database objects when creating?

Comment: Yes, the views is selected, but not shown after put dot following the db..., only tables are visible

Comment: Have you compiled first?

Comment: yes, i CTRL + SHIFT + B , before do anything